How to calculate speed based on applied force?
If I am in a vacuum, and throw a ball with the mass of 1 kilogram, with the force of 20 newtons, how fast would the ball move? What formula can I use to calculate this?

This question cannot be answered since you have not specified the duration over which the force is applied

If you know the distance traveled by the ball before release (the force is applied during the act of throwing), then you can use the Work-Energy Theorm to solve.

Newton's Second Law tells us that Force relates to acceleration via
$$\textbf{F}=m\textbf{a}$$
You are interested in velocity, of which acceleration is the first time-derivative. That means that, to calculate a velocity given a force, we need to integrate both sides of Newton's Second Law. We have
$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\textbf{F}dt=m\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\textbf{a}$$
$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\textbf{F}dt=m(\textbf{v}(t_f)-\textbf{v}(t_i))$$
In your case (I assume), we are dealing with a constant force, so the left integral simply becomes a multiplication by the time duration:
$$\textbf{F}\Delta t=m(\textbf{v}(t_f)-\textbf{v}(t_i))$$
Finally, we can rearrange the equation, isolating the final velocity:
$$\textbf{v}(t_f)=\textbf{v}(t_i)+\frac{1}{m}\textbf{F}\Delta t$$
What this result tells us is that we need more information than just the value of the applied force and the mass of the ball to answer this question. In addition, we need both the initial velocity and the time duration over which the force is applied.
EDIT: I am appending my answer based off of Stevan V. Saban's comment. As they suggest, rather than using the time duration over which the force is applied to determine the answer to your question, you can use the distance the ball moves while it is being forced, if you so choose. You can use the work-energy theorem to do this, or you can parametrize the time duration in terms of the distance traveled by the ball while being forced.
It makes sense, intuitively, that we can use the displacement or the time duration to determine the desired quantity. After all, the time over which we apply the force should determine how far it moves while being forced, so the two variables are not independent.
In either case, the point is that you need more information than you give to find an answer to your problem. Think about it this way: If Person A applies 20N of force to an object for 1 second, and Person B applies 20N of force to the same object for 1 hour, should we expect the velocity of the object that results to be the same in either case?
